# "Normalized odd number of arguments by adding nil " when unmarshalling data in geth client

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I use json.marshal api encoding a struct and then send the marshalled data to geth.  It's oK to unmarshal the data locally, but geth returns a error when unmarshalling it. I don't why, please give me some advice, thanks.

When i specify this error, it returns a message "err="json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go struct field Filterinput.ContractAddress of type common.Address". it's log15 error in geth, but i can't figure out what the log15 is used for

Comment: I figured it out. It's because i embed the struct marshalled with a self-defined type, while in geth client, the json.marshal can't identify this self-defined type. So just changing this type to a common type is OK

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is developing on Go version of Ethereum, and followed the error: “**Normalized odd number of arguments by adding nil**” to here.

It is actually an error message from `log15`. Which means you must feed *even* number items to the log function. For example:

`log.Info("some_str", item1, item2)`

or:

`log.Info("some_str", item1, item2, item3, item4)`

Check out the source code explanation of `log15`:
[here](https://github.com/inconshreveable/log15/blob/master/logger.go)